# Why is the Boolean value of [None] True and the Boolean value of [] False?

Tags: python, list, tuples, boolean

I was working on a project and stumbled across this weird anomaly, apparently the Boolean value for any list or tuple with an None value is True

**Input**

```
print(bool([])) # empty list
print(bool(())) # empty tuple

print(bool([None])) # list with None  
print(bool((None,))) # tuple with None
```

**Output**

```
False
False

True
True
```

can someone give a brief explanation as to why an list/tuple object with presumably None(null) value will have a Boolean value of True instead of False?

Comment: " apparently the Boolean value for any list or tuple with an None value is True" Of course, **any non-empty list or tuple** (or any built-in collection) is *truthy*. This isn't an "weird anomaly". This is clearly documented and unambiguous

Comment: As to "why", well, the answer is *because that is what the language designers decided should be the behavior*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple or a list evaluate to `False` in a boolean context if they're **empty**. `(None,)` and `[None]` are a tuple/list with 1 element (the element `None`), hence not empty... therefore they evaluate to `True` in a boolean context